# Neo4j OGM query for relationships that don't have entity classes

Tags: neo4j-ogm

I have a particular use case, where I have a Neo4j instance with some data mapped to entity classes via OGM and some data that doesn't have an entity class. There are some relationships (without an entity class) that connect these two types of data.

I've been able to use the OGM query method to search for non entity mapped nodes and get back `NodeModel` instances.  However when I try to include relationships I get the following errors:

```
21:11:28.707 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.MetaData - looking for concrete class to resolve label: SPOKE_B
21:11:28.707 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.MetaData - This label is not known in the mapping context. Moving on...
21:11:28.707 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.MetaData - No resolving class found!!
21:11:28.707 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.MetaData - looking for concrete class to resolve label: HUB
21:11:28.707 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.MetaData - This label is not known in the mapping context. Moving on...
21:11:28.707 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.MetaData - No resolving class found!!
21:11:28.707 [main] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper - Relationship (0)-[SGEdge]->(2) cannot be hydrated because one or more required node types are not mapped to entity classes
```

I looked at some of the code and GraphEntityMapper.mapRelationships(), https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/neo4j/ogm/context/GraphEntityMapper.java, only returns relationships if both of the nodes are successfully mapped to an entity class.

So it seems I can't use the OGM query method to get relationships between nodes that aren't mapped to entity classes. Anyone know a way around this?

I realize could use a different driver, but I'd rather not maintain two different driver connections to the same database.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue today and found out a solution.

This is an issue of Neo4j-OGM. You can check the issue [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/309).
As @mangrish said:

> To fix this simply return a,r,n and remove the path from the MATCH
>   statement.

In short, you have to return `StartNode`, `EndNode` besides `RelationshipEntity`. It seems not good but at least it works.
E.g: You have to custom your cypher this way.

```
MATCH (s:StartNode)-[r:SGEdge]->(e:EndNode) return s, r, e
```

Note: You should have a look at their [test](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/test/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/persistence/relationships/RelationshipEntityTest.java#L278)